# Authorizer configuration Exception when calling my lambda function from website

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, lambda-authorizer

I have static website hosted in S3 which is served by Cloudfront.I invoke lambda functions through API gateway Rest API from my website.The API calls return 200 ok response and everything works ok,but sometimes the call fails with the message in X Amazon Header read as Authorizer Configuration Exception. I have configured the lambda invoke policy in my Lambda Authorizer through API gateway and have also enabled API GATEWAY invocation by editing the Trust relationship of my Authorizer Role. Still I keep getting this error infrequently.An API call which was successfully completed earlier would then throw this error upon successive invocations.What would be causing this error? What am I missing here?

Comment: Look at your cloudwatch logs for the Lambda authorizer. And find out what is causing the issue.

Comment: The Api gateway is throwing the error. I have read on here that it is due to API gateway not having necessary permissions to invoke the Lambda Authorizer. if thats the case then why would it not happen all the time rather than intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

This Authorizer Configuration Exception can be caused if your authorizer is returning a response that doesn't match the intended policy document schema.

Check your API Gateway execution logs and your Lambda authorizer logs to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you check it out, once I was having this error with my authorizer and the problem was simply that for some reason the client (okHttp) was sending "authorization" instead of "Authorization" and that was making my script to crash because I was reading event["headers"]["Authorization"], so I don't know if it was the best solution but I just did this:

```
if "Authorization" in event["headers"]:
     login_string = event["headers"]["Authorization"]
else:
     login_string = event["headers"]["authorization"]
```

Not the most elegant but it may help someone in the future.